# Python doesn't recognize the Decoder from pocketsphinx

Tags: python, cmusphinx, attributeerror, decoder, pocketsphinx

I have installed the latest versions of pocketsphinx and sphinxbase (0.8). I try to import pocketsphinx into python code (version 3.4.2 of Python) and to use the "Decoder" like this:

```
try:
    import sphinxbase
    import pocketsphinx as ps

except:
    print ("Pocket sphinx and sphixbase is not installed in your system.
Please install it with package manager.")

speechRec = ps.Decoder(hmm = hmmd, lm = lmdir, dict = dictp, beam = '1e-80')
wavFile = file(wavfile,'rb')
wavFile.seek(44)
speechRec.decode_raw(wavFile)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Decoder'
```

Does somebody know what's wrong?

Comment: Have you named your file `pocketsphinx.py` or any other file in the pwd as `pocketsphinx.py`

Answer (score 2):

As Bhargav has already mentioned, you have named your file `pocketsphinx.py` or have a `pocketsphinx.py` in your path  so you need to rename the file and make sure to delete the `pocketsphinx.pyc` file also. You are trying to import from that file not the pocketsphinx module.

Comment: I didn't name any file like that in the path. But maybe I'm missing something: pocketsphinx.pyx & pocketsphinx.pxd are equivalent to pocketsphinx.py?

Comment: do you have ipython installed?

Comment: also what does `import pocketsphinx; pocketsphinx.__file__` output?

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx-0.0.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pocketsphinx/__init__.pyc

Comment: Ok but you say in your question you are using python3 but it shows yiou have it installed for python2?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that same issue again and could solve it for me. Just for anyone who has this problem in the future, too:

First, I installed a pocketsphinx release from http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-5prealpha.tar.gz. The corresponding `swig/python/__init__.py` which gets installed to `/usr/lib/python<ver>/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py` contains the following:

```
from pocketsphinx import *
```

When I install pocketsphinx from https://pypi.org/project/pocketsphinx/, the corresponding `__init__.py` contains:

```
from .pocketsphinx import *
```

It seems that the tiny dot makes the difference if an import statement like `from pocketsphinx import *` works or if you have to use `from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *`